# LDAP sasl_bind in Python or C

Tags: python-2.7, ldap, python-ldap

I'm trying to bind to a LDAP server using the ldap library in Python. However, every time I try to use sasl_interactive_bind_s() in Python, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: sasl_interactive_bind_s
```

I don't know why this is happening, and the error message isn't very helpful either. Here is the code I'm using. (dc.hostname is just the server name)

```
conn = ldap.initialize("ldap://" + dc.hostname + ":3268")
conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, 5)
conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, ldap.VERSION3)
conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, ldap.OPT_OFF)
conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_RESTART, ldap.OPT_ON)
sasl_cb_value_dict = {}
sasl_cb_value_dict[ldap.sasl.CB_AUTHNAME] = bind_dn
sasl_cb_value_dict[ldap.sasl.CB_PASS] = admin_pw
auth_tokens = ldap.sasl.sasl(sasl_cb_value_dict,"DIGEST-MD5")
conn.sasl_interactive_bind_s("", auth_tokens)
```

In order to try and circumvent this, I also tried to bind using the C function `ldap_sasl_bind_s()` and this helped bind successfully. But, now I don't know how to pass this connection object back to Python, so that I can query the LDAP server. (Note: I used the `ldap_search_ext_s()` function in C, but that never really returned anything, because it took too long to query)

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually It is very helpful. It apparently is you not understanding it. Learn the Python terminology (what is an attribute?) and you will see. And don't add wrong tags. This is Python apparently, not C. See [ask] and provide a [mcve]. I don't see e.g. where you set `conn`.

Comment: I edited my code to show the initialization of conn. And from my understanding, AttributeError means that there's no attribute `sasl_interactive_bind_s()` associated with the `conn` object. However, this is not true, cuz when I display all the attributes of the `conn` object, `sasl_interactive_bind_s()` is one of them.